# Create webservice from wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

Is there a way to generate corresponding web service (server) from existing wsdl file in java (specially by using Intellij IDEA)?

It seems a very simple question, but I can't find any solution.

Comment: take a look at jax-ws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be surprised if it exists.
The wsdl describes the interface of the service, i.e. what are the available methods, what parameters do they require, what do they return, thrown exceptions, ...

Getting an implementation from an interface requires thinking :

- knowing exactly what the methods are supposed to do
- choosing a way, among many other possible ways, to achieve it

As far as I know wsimport allows you to create a proxy on the client side, which is not what you're asking for.

Comment: Actually I want to create a proxy for existing web service and force clients to use my proxy to communicate to target web service. In proxy I can do some authentication and authorization and ... .

Comment: In order to create a proxy for an existing web services whose wsdl you have : use wsimport in the command line.
1. Open the command line
2. set wsdlURL=http://...?wsdl (the url of your wsdl)
3. cd %java_home%/bin
4. wsimport -d folderWhereYouWantToSaveTheGeneratedFiles -keep wsdlURL

Then you take the generated code and put it in your project and use it for your proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Use **JAX-WS** `wsimport` which is a commandline tool

The wsimport tool generates JAX-WS portable artifacts, such as:

- Service Endpoint Interface (SEI)
- Service
- Exception class mapped from wsdl:fault (if any)
- Async Reponse Bean derived from response wsdl:message (if any)
- JAXB generated value types (mapped java classes from schema types)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html

The method you are using is called **Top-Down** or **Contract first** this might help you googling for future problems.